# Paypal IPN - Getting + then losing data?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently using the following library:

https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php/tree/master/samples/IPN

And Paypal IPN seems to be working fine... I can successfully checkout and all of the POST data from Paypal is logged to my server, only problem is - How do I check against it when the user is back on the site?

I currently have the return URL set to the same as the IPN url (look in github for code) and after I get all of the valid data, the user gets returned to the IPN page and it says invalid.

Not quite sure, any thoughts?

Comment: Should I store data in a SESSION maybe?

Answer (score 1):

IPN should NOT be used as the return URL.

- Return URL brings the buyer back to your site. The page at the return URL should display either a generic thank you page, or a page indicating the status of the buyer's order. Which one of the above to choose, depends on the PayPal product you select, your integration and your purchasing flow.
- The script URL of the IPN listener is used to automate your order handling process. The IPN listener gets the IPN messages, processes your order in your own defined way.

IPN listener should post back very specific data to PayPal IPN endpoint with HTTP Status 200. If it also outputs a page, it makes things too complicated. You would need to differentiate between a buyer visit and a PayPal IPN message, and need to do corresponding display or IPN verification. To make things simple, separating the two things into two pages / scripts would be better and more logical.

I think this is the reason why your buyer gets "invalid": your IPN listener gets the request data when a buyer returns to your listener, and uses the data to verify IPN with PayPal. PayPal returns "invalid" as the data are not from valid IPN messages and thus cannot be verified.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Php dev and haven't looked, but if you really want to use the same URL (I wouldn't - they serve different purposes), then the difference would be the (http) request method:

- `GET` for a redirect and
- `POST` for IPN

That would be one way you'd determine what kind of *Request* that url is getting and handle as you deem fit.